Best way to implement this mirror mechanic?
I wanted to ask for some mechanical guidance, since I don't have much direct design experience.
I wanted to design a robot that would calculate the direction of sunlight and do some vector algebra to orient a mirror such that the sunlight is reflected in a desired direction. I already did the vector algebra to solve for the mirror plane's normal vector, but now I'm stuck on the "how do I design a mechanism to do that?".
I want to have control over the yaw (-180, 180] and pitch [0, ~90] of a simple square mirror being held. Maybe stepper motors or high-quality servos would work well (some opinions on that would be nice too), but it's the actual idea of the best mechanism to do this that I want.
Here's a Desmos page I made to simulate that vector algebra to illustrate what I mean.
Desmos page simulating a vector reflection
(You have full control over the yaw and pitch of the desired vector in blue, but in theory no control over the incident purple vector, and the orange vector is the mirror's unit normal packaging all rotational information).

Try an image search for "2-axis gimbals". They're usually used to keep cameras aligned while the operator is moving. In your case you would keep the gimbal base fixed while adjusting the gimbal.
The other thing that comes to mind is astronomy telescope trackers which adjust the telescope to keep pointing at a certain astronomical object while the earth rotates.
